# sendkeys does not work for File input selenium 2.39 Firefox 31

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-io, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am working on automating file upload for my site. I am using FF 31, selenium 2.39. The issue that i am seeing is that file upload with below java code works on Chrome 37 but does not work on FF 31.
I tried getting it working with selenium 43 and selenium 39 for FF 28-31 versions yet so no results. Then I added inline style with opacity set to 1 from 0 as the style of the input element was not visible using javascript.After executing the javascript i printed out the characteristics. I see that element is enabled and displayed and has the opacity set to 1, that is all my changes applied. still my sendKeys() doesnt seem to work with it.Although i did think of AutoIT i didnt want to add another tool and buy more trouble for myself(compatibility issues between my site/selenium/browser/autoit).Can you guys suggest something that i can do to fix this issue?

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='img']"));
input.sendKeys("C:/Pictures/img1.gif");

final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('img').style.opacity=\"1\";");

<i class="coral-Icon">
<input id="img" class="FileUpload" type="file" onchange="preview();" data-upload-url="URL" name="file">
</i>

System.out.println("enabled??== " + input.isEnabled()+ " === "+ input.isDisplayed()+" style "+ input.getAttribute("style")); 
console-output : enabled??== true === true style opacity: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the path error on the windows m/c I use. I added a check function based on OS running to change the path of the file.

String imgPath = imagePath.replaceAll("/", "\\");